# How to represent one variable in terms of others in an equation set in Mathematicas?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation

I have an pretty complex equation set [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOUIi.png)

I want to solve Vo in terms of Vin.

But when I clicked Ctrl+Enter (a.k.a Evaluate Cell), nothing happened.

How to fix it? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
Simplify[Reduce[eqn, Vo]]
```

works.

If you can include any assumptions (as a second argument to Simplify or by giving those along with your equations to Reduce) that you have about some variables not being zero then the result might be simpler. In any case, you look through each of the terms returned from Simplify to try to find the case that matches your real world problem.